# Python - How to uninstall OpenCV?

Tags: python, c++, macos, opencv

I have problem in uninstalling OpenCV. I have installed OpenCV 3 using the tutorial from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/15/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-osx/). I am installing it with Python binding and it is installed within a Python virtual environment. My system is Mac El Capitan

Now, I want to reinstall/recompile it, because I have some problems in compiling it in C++ (and also because I do want to experiment with the new module that comes with it). In my `/usr/local/` folder, there is an `include` folder, but there is no `opencv` folders whatsoever. I think I also have the same problem with the `/usr/lib/` folder of mine. I managed to find some of the header files, but it is inside the folder `opencv` I have downloaded before (from the source) and not inside the `usr/local/include/` in which it should have been.

I have tried to `sudo make uninstall`, but got this error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target uninstall
CMake Error at cmake_uninstall.cmake:6 (MESSAGE):
  Cannot find install manifest:
  "/Users/hilman_dayo/opencv/build/install_manifest.txt"


make[3]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall] Error 1
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/uninstall.dir/rule] Error 2
make: *** [uninstall] Error 2
```

So, what step should I take in deleting the OpenCV, and from there, delete my virtual environment so I can reinstall from scratch? Thanks.

Comment: did you run **make install** after compilation ?

Comment: As far as I know, yes. Now, I just need the right solution to delete all OpenCV related files so I can start from scratch.